# Logon password show div localstorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

How to make it so that after logging in with the correct password, the div field shows and is stored in localstorage, and that the password fields and the login button hide after logging in with the correct password is successful

[Jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/thvinic/7ywbraz5/2/)

(For reference although localStorage issues on Stack Snippets)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#foo').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings().toggle();
    //you need to pass string values, your variables display & block was not defined
    localStorage.setItem('display', $(this).siblings().is(':visible'));
  });
  var block = localStorage.getItem('display');
  if (block == 'true') {
    $('#bar').show()
  }
});

// Get references to the elements you'll be working with
var input = document.getElementById("password");
var div = document.getElementById("HIDDENDIV");
var btn = document.getElementById("button");

// Set up event handlers in JavaScript
button.addEventListener("click", validate);

function validate() {
  if (input.value == '123') {
    // No need to add a "show" class. Just remove the "hidden" class.
    div.classList.remove('hidden');
    // Or, add it:
    input.classList.add("hidden");
    $(this).siblings().toggle();
    //you need to pass string values, your variables display & block was not defined
    localStorage.setItem('display', $(this).siblings().is(':visible'));
    var block = localStorage.getItem('display');
    if (block == 'true') {
      $('#bar').show()
    }
    if ($("#bar:visible").length) {
      // it's visible
    } else {
      alert("Janela Acendeu!");
    }
  } else {
    password.focus(); // <-- If you don't do this first, your select code won't work
    password.setSelectionRange(0, password.value.length);
    alert('Senha Incorreta ! tente novamente...');
  }
}

input.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    // No reason to simulate a button click. Just call the code that needs to be run.
    validate();
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="password">
<br>
<input id="button" type="button" value="Login">
<div id="HIDDENDIV" class="hidden">bla</div>

<div id="container">
  <a id="foo" href="javascript:void(0);">Click Me</a>
  <div class="conteudo1" id="bar">xxxxxx</div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

the password for access in the example is *123*

The idea would be, the content will be shown and keep showing after successful login.
Any ideas and help please?

Comment: WARNING! You should never, ever store passwords in plaintext anywhere on the frontend. You should instead save passwords hashed (bcrypt) and salted on the backend and use hash comparison methods in order to check/validate. All over SSL.

Comment: You would need to check what your storage contains on page load, and show/hide elements based on that. Right now, you appear to only be doing it when the user explicitly clicks on a button.